# Как вставить теги в выделенный текст

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, мне нужно в поле input, в котором имеется некий текст, предположим, "Жил бы орел, он был очень большой", выделить текст "он был очень". Жму кнопку вставить и текст в поле меняется на "Жил бы орел, `<a>он был очень</a>` большой"

Как это сделать так и не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю это будет полезно http://habrahabr.ru/post/38077/

Answer (score 0):

да, читал этот пост, уже реализовал задучу

```
$.fn.textSelected = function(open, close) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();
        var start = $this[0].selectionStart;
        var end = $this[0].selectionEnd;
        $this.val( value.substr(0, start) + open + value.substring(start, end) + close + value.substring(end, value.length) );
    });
};

$('a[href="#select"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this).parents(".blockRelated");
    $('input[name="link_title"]').textSelected('<a>','</a>');
    return false;
});
```